# Dropping duplicates in Pandas excluding one column

Tags: python, pandas

This seems simple, but I can not find any information on it on the internet.

I have a dataframe like below:

```
City    State Zip           Date        Description       
Earlham IA    50072-1036    2014-10-10  Postmarket Assurance: Devices
Earlham IA    50072-1036    2014-10-10  Compliance: Devices
Madrid  IA    50156-1748    2014-09-10  Drug Quality Assurance
```

How can I eliminate duplicates that match 4 of 5 columns? The column not matching being `Description`.

The result would be

```
City    State Zip           Date        Description       
Earlham IA    50072-1036    2014-10-10  Postmarket Assurance: Devices
Madrid  IA    50156-1748    2014-09-10  Drug Quality Assurance
```

I found online that `drop_duplicates` with the `subset` parameter could work, but I am unsure of how I can apply it to multiple columns.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

You've actually found the solution. For multiple columns, subset will be a list.

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['City', 'State', 'Zip', 'Date'])
```

Or, just by stating the column to be ignored:

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=df.columns.difference(['Description']))
```