# How to remove duplicates rows based on partial strings in Python

Tags: python, pandas

If i have a dataframe as follows in which 01 and 02, 03 and 04, 05 and 06 are same cites:

```
id    city
01    New York City
02    New York
03    Tokyo City
04    Tokyo
05    Shanghai City
06    Shanghai
07    Beijing City
08    Paris
09    Berlin
```

How can I drop duplicates cites and get following dataframe? Thanks.

```
id    city
01    New York 
02    Tokyo 
03    Shanghai
04    Beijing City
05    Paris
06    Berlin
```

Comment: Can't Beijing City become Beijing?

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html

Comment: Sorry, in my real data, it's not regular.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dropping duplicates in Pandas excluding one column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38445416/dropping-duplicates-in-pandas-excluding-one-column)

Comment: @JRibkr My friend it is not the exact duplicate. It needs some data manipulation before dropping duplicates. Thanks for your efforts though

Comment: @mad_ I will be blunt. it clearly shows that author has not taken time to search for solution. It's replace and drop_duplicate solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace City part with null string and apply group by keeping the first row

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,4],'city':['New York City','New York','Tokyo City','Tokyo']})
```

df looks like this

```
    city            id
0   New York City   1
1   New York        2
2   Tokyo City      3
3   Tokyo           4
```

Apply replace and group by to get first row in each group

```
df.city=df.city.str.replace('City','').str.strip()
df.groupby('city').first().sort_values('id')
```

Output:

```
city       id
New York    1
Tokyo       3
```

Or use drop_duplicates on subset of columns. Thanks @JR ibkr

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset='city')
```

Comment: don't you think this is overkill. Why not to use drop_duplicates? By default it will keep 1st occurrence.

Comment: @JRibkr the default behavior of `drop_duplicates` is to check all the columns for duplicate values but can use subset param to check for duplications in specific fields. Edited the answer. Thanks

Comment: Can you update your solution to reflect the easy way? Lots of people lookup to stackoverflow for easy & efficient solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is much easier in pandas now with drop_duplicates and the keep parameter.

```
# dataset
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,4],'city':['New York City','New York','Tokyo City','Tokyo']})
# replace values
df.city = df.city.str.replace('City','').str.strip()
# drop duplicate (answer of original question)
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['city'])
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html

Comment: Then create a dataframe with city name part and apply drop_duplicates

Comment: This question is duplicate question of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38445416/dropping-duplicates-in-pandas-excluding-one-column/38445485 .